# c++ graphics and mmorpg?

Tags: java, c++, graphics, multiplayer

i have been planning on making a 2d mmorpg game for a long time. I have learned java and android programming for a few years, and also i learned some c++. I know all of the basic of c++ because it is kind of like java. one thing i do not know and i have been searching all over for is using graphics, and in the near future also making an mmorpg. can anyone recommend on any tutorials? or can help me in any way? i am using Eclipse for Java and Code::blocks for c++. am i using the right programs?

Thank you!

BTW, sorry if it is the wrong place to ask, if it is, please tell me where i can ask it.

Comment: The far better place would be http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, and is openGL good for an mmorpg game? if so, can you give me a link for a tutorial?

Comment: @fyr Thanks for the recommendation, i posted my question here: 
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24337/c-graphics-and-mmorpg

Comment: For Java, see [2D Graphics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/).

Comment: MMORPG is not only massively multiplayer, but also massively complex. "I, alone, write a MMORPG" is similarly doomed as "I kind of know C++, because C++ is kind of like Java". You may want to reconsider your plans and a) start with something smaller, and b) learn whatever language you will finally use _properly_ for such a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for Graphics you should probably go with OpenGL. But as you are making a game it might be wise to use either SDL or SFML. In this case I would advise SFML. SFML is opengl friendly, it basically uses it! But it also comes with other packages such as networking and sound.

This is the link to the SFML library: http://www.sfml-dev.org/
This is the link to SDL: http://www.libsdl.org/

If you want though you could try out using just OpenGL but it adds more development time as you need to learn the platform specific library (Win32 API for windows, X11 Window for linux, not sure about mac) to create the window OpenGL renders to. Whereas SDL and SFML are already prepared for each OS and will greatly reduce the time you spend on writing code for making your game.

Go with whatever you wish, but I highly recommend that you use an already made game development library.

Edit: Note that you can use OpenGL functions whilst using SDL or SFML. Essentially they are a wrapper around the platform specific libraries. Thank you KillianDS for pointing out that I had not been clear about that fact.

Comment: Your "platform specific" reasoning has nothing to do with OpenGL, there are enough platform independent window creation wrappers to handle window creation/device input/... for you. You mention two of them yourself, it's not because you do the opengl rendering yourself you can't use the other parts of those libraries

Comment: Which is why I stated "If you want though you could try out using just OpenGL" meaning without a wrapper and it is also why I mentioned SFML and SDL. I will edit the answer to clarify that OpenGL functions can be used.